# Moving dependencies to another folder during release build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I am working on windows application which generates an exe along with config and required dlls as shown in following screenshot. I want to move the highlighted elements in separate folder called dependencies when I build for release. How should I go about that? I am using visual studio 2017.

[image]

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Sorry was travelling out. Yes it did work Now I want move pdb and xml file as well ? If I just extend the include section line this:  <FilesToMove Include="bin\Release\*.dll,*.pdb,*.xml"/>  It stops working. How should I go abut them?

Comment: And another thing is though my dlls are moved to another folder my exe stops to work.How should I ask my exe to load dll from new location?

Comment: yes, .exe file will find the dll files in the same folder, since you have moved the dll file out of .exe folder, .exe could not find it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Moving dependencies to another folder during release build

You can use [Move task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/move-task?view=vs-2017) with [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2017) in the custom target.

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag `</Project>`, place below scripts:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToMove Include="PathToFiles\*.dll"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="MoveFiles" AfterTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <Message Text="Move Files to the dependencies folder when I build for release"></Message>
    <Move
    SourceFiles="@(FilesToMove)"
    DestinationFolder="PathToFiles\dependencies"
    />
  </Target>
```

With the condition `Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' "`, those .dll files are moved  to the dependencies after build. You just need specify the relative path of those .dll files.

Hope this helps.